# What is this when using Excel and SQL Server Sum?

Tags: sql, excel, math, sum

I have problem with SQL Server and Excel when using SUM function

You can see attach image to know what I did mean

I wany to sum this values and I must get 0 as total

```
120
-6
-24
-1
-24
-12
-12
-1.2
-1
-12
-12
-1.5
-2
-4
-5
-0.6
-1.5
-0.1
-0.1
```

but what is this ?

```
-2.94209E-15
```

Excel Values Sum

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype for this column in the SQL Server?

Comment: Change the type of the cell where `SUM` formula is from Custom/scientific to number

Comment: datatype in the sql server is: float
I was write code in c# to sum values row by row of column like:

loop
total += total;

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, convert the values to Number

Comment: Correct, but I want to know what is this number : -2.94209E-15 
and why I got this result